# How to skip cells when creating an array in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to cells to be excluded from an array formula when I create the array, as in not have the array in those cells. Is this possible?

In this image, the left table is the data that I'm using to produce the reports in the center and on the right. In the actual spreadsheet the data is spread out across multiple sheets, and more or those sheets are added monthly.

Currently the center table is what using an array for output produces, this causes the sums to be duplicated on the rows where the task number is for the subitems. I cannot (am not allowed to) remove the task number for these subitems.

The table on the right is what I have currently, with a formula in each of the filled amount boxes. However, since this formula in reality consists of multiple sumifs for the different data sheets, I'd like to have to only update one cell and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to update the whole column of cells. This table is also what cells I'd like for the array to be in.

A formula from the actual sheet:

```
=SUMIFS('April 18'!S:S,'April 18'!M:M,Summary!A:A,'April 18'!O:O,"4.2018")+SUMIFS('May 18'!T:T,'May 18'!N:N,Summary!A:A,'May 18'!P:P,"4.2018")+SUMIFS('July 18'!$U:$U,'July 18'!$N:$N,Summary!$A:$A,'July 18'!$Q:$Q,"4.2018")+SUMIFS('June 18'!$U:$U,'June 18'!$N:$N,Summary!$A:$A,'June 18'!$Q:$Q,"4.2018")
```

[image: Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

Lots of little things to assume here, but as they say, the devil is in the details.

My assumptions will be that the Task Numbers for subitems are identical to the non-subitem that will lead them in the table. As an example, cell K3 contains a non-subitem since it is the first of one or more that have a particular Task Number. K4, K5, and K6 have subitems because their Task Numbers are the same as K2's Task Number.

If this is so, you can use the following formula in column L's cells:

```
=IF(J2=J1,"",SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F$3:$F:$13,$B:$B,"7.2018")
```

For the successful `IF()` tests, if you need 0's instead of "", just change that part. An example of when issues can arise would be some ways of adding the values in this column (column L). If you'd like the cells blank, yet having a 0 for that kind of concern, just format the column so that the third formatting parameter (for when a cell equals 0) as nothing. For example:  `0,000.00;-0,000.00;` and cells with a value of 0 will display as blank.

The rest of the formula is the formula the picture shows.

If this is not a correct assumption about non-subitems and subitems, all is not lost. You surely have some way we do not see of identifying subitems as such. And presumably non-subitems as such. Just use the same approach above, but use that way you have for identifying the difference between items. I used the method I did since it looks like it is valid and let the solution be complete in what is presented. But the cleanest way is using whatever way you have to identify the difference.

I point out that you must surely have one because of the indentation of subitems. That has to happen due to some known difference. It is not something that Excel would bring along with a value found somewhere. It WILL do that with numbers if a cell with default formatting gets a formula referring to some formatted cell. But not strings. So there must be some way. Just check for that difference in the `IF()` test.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions and clarification.

1. Your original formula is not verified. Below example uses a simplified data and basic formula using SUMIFS
2. It's assumed that you are using Right Indent to indent sub items. If you are using Spaces by any chance please use Right Indent button to align sub items. Also it's assumed that all your items are basically Left Aligned in the respective cells.

In this example sample input table is in cells A1:A13 and output table is F2:F14.

Open VBA Editor by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>. Insert a Module (From the Insert Menu) and paste the following code into it.

```
Function IndLevl(cell As Range)

    Application.Volatile
    IndLevl = cell.IndentLevel

End Function
```

This creates a User Defined Function (UDF) that accepts Cell as range and returns the indent level as number. No validations are in place so avoid passing a range of cells as input like A1:A4 to it. Just pass a single cell as parameter e.g. `=IndLevl(A4)`

If using Excel 2007 or above save the file as .xlsm (Macro Enabled Excel Sheet)

Now in your output table warp the formula in an IF with checking for Indent Level first and then deciding if to execute the formula or just let it be Blanks.

```
=IF(IndLevl(G3)>0,"",SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,F3,$B:$B,1.2))
```

Drag down the formula to required cells. See the below screenshot. You can wrap your formula in an IF and then if needed convert it to an Array Formula as desired.

Note that the `Application.Volatile` statement makes the formula volatile. Yet it won't execute itself if you just change the indent level later on. In such a cases just press F9 to re-calculate the sheet.

See the below screenshot.

[image]